# Grafana dashboard shows no data

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, prometheus, grafana

After I set up prometheus with mongodb_exporter I didn't get any data in grafana ,
and the localhost:9216/metrics doesn't show any mongodb metrics except "mongodb_up"
but for me i need all mongodb metrics in order to do the monitoring .
.

.
this my metrics

```
# HELP mongodb_up Whether MongoDB is up.
# TYPE mongodb_up gauge
mongodb_up 1
# HELP process_cpu_seconds_total Total user and system CPU time spent in seconds.
# TYPE process_cpu_seconds_total counter
process_cpu_seconds_total 0.11
# HELP process_max_fds Maximum number of open file descriptors.
# TYPE process_max_fds gauge
process_max_fds 1.048576e+06
# HELP process_open_fds Number of open file descriptors.
# TYPE process_open_fds gauge
process_open_fds 16
# HELP process_resident_memory_bytes Resident memory size in bytes.
# TYPE process_resident_memory_bytes gauge
process_resident_memory_bytes 1.6887808e+07
# HELP process_start_time_seconds Start time of the process since unix epoch in seconds.
# TYPE process_start_time_seconds gauge
process_start_time_seconds 1.65307162516e+09
# HELP process_virtual_memory_bytes Virtual memory size in bytes.
# TYPE process_virtual_memory_bytes gauge
process_virtual_memory_bytes 7.34683136e+08
# HELP process_virtual_memory_max_bytes Maximum amount of virtual memory available in bytes.
# TYPE process_virtual_memory_max_bytes gauge
process_virtual_memory_max_bytes 1.8446744073709552e+19
```

This my docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  mongo : 
    image: "mongo:latest"
    ports: 
      - 2000:27017

  mongodb-exporter:
    image: "percona/mongodb_exporter:0.32.0"
    ports:
      - 9216:9216
    command: 
      
      - "--mongodb.uri=mongodb://mongo:27017"
      - "--mongodb.collstats-colls=Test.Listings"
      - "--discovering-mode"
      - "--mongodb.direct-connect"   
    
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus/:/etc/prometheus/
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
      - '--web.console.libraries=/usr/share/prometheus/console_libraries'
      - '--web.console.templates=/usr/share/prometheus/consoles'
    ports:
      - 9090:9090

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

Answer (score 2):

For bitnami/mongodb-exporter:0.32.0-debian-10-r3 passing "--collect-all" as additional parameter in command worked for me to get the metrics. So the modification would look as follows:

```yaml
    command: 
      - "--mongodb.uri=mongodb://mongo:27017"
      - "--mongodb.collstats-colls=Test.Listings"
      - "--discovering-mode"
      - "--mongodb.direct-connect"  
      - "--collect-all"
```

However, the available dashboards make use of older metric names so my dashboards that I picked from under percona's repository even after modifying the datasources did not get populated.

One suggestion regarding when I was searching online was that is adding "--compatible-mode" as well but that has been reported to be not working with mongo:5 and up. I have yet to confirm with previous releases such as mongo:4.2

I am currently trying to convert the queries of the dashboards accordingly with the new metric names though it ain't pretty.

Answer (score 0):

Adding --collect-all and --compatible-mode worked for me with the following configuration :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongodb-prom
  namespace: "labs"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: mongodb
    helm.sh/chart: mongodb-12.1.12
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: mongodb-prom
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: mongodb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate  
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: mongodb
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: mongodb-prom
      app.kubernetes.io/component: mongodb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: mongodb
        helm.sh/chart: mongodb-12.1.12
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: mongodb-prom
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
        app.kubernetes.io/component: mongodb
    spec:
  
  serviceAccountName: mongodb-prom
  affinity:
      
    podAntiAffinity:
      preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        - podAffinityTerm:
            labelSelector:
              matchLabels:
                app.kubernetes.io/name: mongodb
                app.kubernetes.io/instance: mongodb-prom
                app.kubernetes.io/component: mongodb
            namespaces:
              - "labs"
            topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
          weight: 100
      
  securityContext:
    fsGroup: 1001
    sysctls: []
  
  containers:
    - name: mongodb
      image: docker.io/bitnami/mongodb:5.0.9-debian-10-r15
      imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
      securityContext:
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 1001
      env:
        - name: BITNAMI_DEBUG
          value: "false"
        - name: MONGODB_ROOT_USER
          value: "root"
        - name: MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-prom
              key: mongodb-root-password
        - name: ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
          value: "no"
        - name: MONGODB_SYSTEM_LOG_VERBOSITY
          value: "0"
        - name: MONGODB_DISABLE_SYSTEM_LOG
          value: "no"
        - name: MONGODB_DISABLE_JAVASCRIPT
          value: "no"
        - name: MONGODB_ENABLE_JOURNAL
          value: "yes"
        - name: MONGODB_PORT_NUMBER
          value: "27017"
        - name: MONGODB_ENABLE_IPV6
          value: "no"
        - name: MONGODB_ENABLE_DIRECTORY_PER_DB
          value: "no"
      ports:
        - name: mongodb
          containerPort: 27017
      
      volumeMounts:
        - name: datadir
          mountPath: /bitnami/mongodb
        - name: datadir
          mountPath: /tmp           
    - name: metrics
      image: docker.io/bitnami/mongodb-exporter:0.32.0-debian-11-r5
      imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
      securityContext:
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 1001
      command:
        - /bin/bash
        - -ec
      args:
        - |
          /bin/mongodb_exporter --web.listen-address ":9216" --mongodb.uri "mongodb://$MONGODB_ROOT_USER:$(echo $MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD | sed -r "s/@/%40/g;s/:/%3A/g")@localhost:27017/admin?" --collect-all --compatible-mode 
      env:
        - name: MONGODB_ROOT_USER
          value: "root"
        - name: MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-prom
              key: mongodb-root-password
      ports:
        - name: metrics
          containerPort: 9216
      livenessProbe:
        failureThreshold: 3
        initialDelaySeconds: 15
        periodSeconds: 5
        successThreshold: 1
        timeoutSeconds: 5
        httpGet:
          path: /
          port: metrics
      readinessProbe:
        failureThreshold: 3
        initialDelaySeconds: 5
        periodSeconds: 5
        successThreshold: 1
        timeoutSeconds: 1
        httpGet:
          path: /
          port: metrics
      resources:
        limits: {}
        requests: {}
  volumes:
    - name: datadir
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: mongodb
```